# How to get rid of null values/elements of a 2D array while writing it on a CSV file and displaying it on a table?

Tags: java, arrays, csv, user-interface, null

I have an issue on my Java code where it keeps on displaying null values on my GUI, specifically from its 2D array(String[][] cust = new String[10][7] - this is a universal 2D array), how can I get rid of these values while writing it on a CSV file and displaying it on my table in my GUI, it also fully iterates the whole size of the array(which is 10) on the table thus showing all the nulls . I have made an if statement inside my for loop in getting rid of the null values which is cust[r][0] != null but still it didn't worked well.

[image: Table from my GUI where it displays null values]

[image: CSV file being written where it has null values]

Here's my source code for the writing and reading of the CSV file, and displaying it on the table:

```
  public void writeCustomerCSV(){  // everything in this snippet code works fine(it creates a CSV file which stores the inputs of the user)
   try{
       BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\RALPH\\Documents\\Database Java CSV\\customers.csv"));
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
       int y;
       for(int x = 0; x < itemTo2D.length; x++){
           for(y = 0; y < itemTo2D[0].length; y++){
               if(itemTo2D[x] != null){
                   sb.append(itemTo2D[x][y]);
                 
               }
                 sb.append(",");
           }
            
           sb.append("-");  //separation for rows
           sb.append(",");  // separation for columns
            
       }
        
       bw.write(sb.toString());
       bw.close();
        
   }  catch (Exception ex){
        
     }
   
  }



public void readCustomerCSV(){  // reads the contents of the CSV file    
    int read2DStringIndex = 0;
    int newVarIndexer = 0;
    String[] fromfile = {};   // 1d string for getting the columns(7 columns) of the CSV file

 

    try{
         BufferedReader br = new  BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\RALPH\\Documents\\Database Java CSV\\customers.csv"));
         String line;
         
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
             fromfile = line.split(",");  //separates the columns by a comma
         }
        
        
        
    } catch (Exception ex){
        
    }
    
    for(int g = 0; g < fromfile.length; g++){  
         if(fromfile[g].equals("-")){   //if there is a presence of a dash, it increments the read2DStringINdex (row index) of the 2D array     
             read2DStringIndex++;
              newVarIndexer = 0;

         }
         else{
               cust[read2DStringIndex][newVarIndexer] = fromfile[g];    //cust is the 2D array(declared universal) which is going to display the values to the table
               newVarIndexer++;

         }
    }
    

    DefaultTableModel tblmodelll = (DefaultTableModel) mainTable.getModel();  // table
    setrowcount = 0;

    for(int r = 0; r < cust.length; r++){
        if(setrowcount == 0){
           tblmodelll.setRowCount(0);
        }
        if(cust[r][0] != null){  //gets rid of the null but it is not working 
           tblmodelll.addRow(cust[r]);  //displays the cust(2D array) data to table 
         }
    
           setrowcount++; 
   }


    
    
    for(int h = 0; h < cust.length; h++){  //prints cust (2D array) , just to check what data is being stored
      for(int p = 0; p < cust[0].length; p++){
          System.out.println(cust[h][p] + ",");
       }
   }
```

Comment: You can Use **commons-lang3**  package to convert null to blank. Maven dependency given below


`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>`

And You use: StringUtils.defaultString(yourString);

This converts null to balnk

Comment: From the code in your question: `if(cust[r][0] != null){  //gets rid of the null but it is not working` That's because you need to check for the **string** "null", as in: `if(cust[r][0].equals("null")){`, since your CSV file does not contain actual nulls, it contains the word "null".

Comment: @ankurpramanik is this the one? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.9

Comment: @Abra ok your given statement worked!! I just modified it a bit since it results to null pointer exception. Here it is:  try{                
            if(cust[r][0].equals("null") == false){  //gets rid of the null but it is not working 
               tblmodelll.addRow(cust[r]);  //displays the cust(2D array) data to table 
               }
            } catch(Exception e){
                
            }

Comment: @Ralph Henry Yes your link is right